# List stuck keyboard keys

Tags: windows, gratis, keyboard-listener

I'm looking for a program that can list all keyboard keys that are stuck. I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. If possible, the program should be free (unlike [PassMark KeyboardTest™](http://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm)) and handle the case when several keyboards are connected to the computer i.e. say on which keyboard the key is stuck.

PassMark KeyboardTest™ :

[image]